# Attempting a Binary Search on a Object Array (Comparable)

Tags: javascript, java, binary-search-tree, comparator, binary-search

I've been struggling a couple days now attempting to write this code. Basically,we have to perform a binarySearch based on the SSN of Comparable "Student" objects in a Student array.  After performing the binarySearch on the SSN, the student who is associated with that SSN's first and last name should print out. I am finding difficulty in writing the binarySearch.

Here's my code so far:
my Student class:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{


    private String firstName, lastName, SSN, bankAccount;


    public Student(String first, String last, String ssn, String bkacct) {

        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.SSN = ssn;
        this.bankAccount = bkacct;
    }   


    //toString method
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee: [FirstName = " + firstName + ", LastName = " + lastName + ", SSN = " + SSN + ", BankAccount = "
                + bankAccount + "]";
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {

        return (lastName.equals(((Student)other).getLastName()) &&
                firstName.equals(((Student)other).getFirstName())&&
                SSN.equals(((Student)other).getSSN()) && 
                bankAccount.equals(((Student)other).getBankAccount()));
    }


    //Sorting the array based on SSN
    public int compareTo(Student target) {


        int result;

        if (lastName.equals(target.getLastName()))
            result = SSN.compareTo((String) target.getSSN());
        else 

            result = SSN.compareTo((String) target.getSSN());

        return result;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public Object getSSN() {
        return SSN;
    }

    public String getBankAccount() {
        return bankAccount;
    }
```

and my class where i perform my binarySearch

```
public class ObjectBubbleSortTest {



    //setting up binarySearch to find Array
    public static <Student extends Comparable<Student>> int binarySearch(Student[] student, Student target) {

        int low = 0;
        int high = student.length - 1;
        int middle = (low+high + 1)/2;
        int location = -1;


        while((low <= high) && (location == -1)) {

            if (student[middle].compareTo(target) == 0 ) {
                location = middle;
            }
            else if (student[middle].compareTo(target) < 0) { //middle element too high
                    high = middle - 1;
                }

            else {
                low = middle + 1;
            }

            middle = (low + high + 1)/2;

        }
        return location;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //EMPLOYEES OF BURGER KING
        Student[] student = new Student[5];

        //order: First Name, Last Name, SSN, Bank_Account_Number 
        student[0] = new Student("Adam", "Sarrone", "1234567", "9022345"); 
        student[1] = new Student("Ryan", "Petrowvoksi", "4345123", "0120345"); 
        student[2] = new Student("Jenn", "Henderson", "8124512", "564214"); 
        student[3] = new Student("Ricky", "Jean", "3512345", "612345");
        student[4] = new Student("Dare", "Ogun", "421451", "198213");


        System.out.println("Original array order: \n");
            for (Student element : student) 
                System.out.print(element + "\n");


            ObjectBubbleSorter.bubbleSort(student);

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("\nSorted array order: \n");
            for (Student element : student) 
                System.out.print(element + "\n");

            System.out.println();

            //need helping figuring out why the binary search is not printing out

            int studentName = binarySearch(student, "421451");

            System.out.print(studentName);

        }

    }
```

I am also getting an error on "int studentName = binarySearch" stating The method binarySearch(Student[], Student) in the type ObjectBubbleSortTest is not applicable for the arguments (Student[], String). I understand what it means but struggling to make my binarySearch adaptable to fix that error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be clear if you read the error message once again carefully.

```
"int studentName = binarySearch" stating The method binarySearch(Student[], Student) in the type ObjectBubbleSortTest is not applicable for the arguments (Student[], String).
```

So basically the method signature you have is `int binarySearch(Student[] student, Student target)`, but when you call it in `main()` it's `binarySearch(student, "421451");`

You may want to instead call the method like `binarySearch(student, student[4]);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I called the binarySearch in that manner because I want to perform a search on the SSN and not the student's element. I'm probably just confusing myself. If anyone has a method to help I'd appreciate it, I need a light bulb right now to spark my thought process.